# Ignore set values for product quantityInformation

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I try to ignore the set values on a product for quantityInformation and have created a CustomCartCollector in which my collect function looks like this:

```
public function collect(CartDataCollection $data, Cart $original, SalesChannelContext $context, CartBehavior $behavior): void
    {
        $lineItems = $this->getProducts($original->getLineItems());

        /** @var LineItem $lineItem */
        foreach ($lineItems as $lineItem) {
            if ($lineItem['item']->hasExtension('FooProductUnit')
                && $lineItem['item']->getExtension('FooProductUnit')['unit'] !== 'Stk.') {
                $lineItem['item']->getQuantityInformation()->setMaxPurchase(100);
                $lineItem['item']->getQuantityInformation()->setMinPurchase(1);
                $lineItem['item']->getQuantityInformation()->setPurchaseSteps(1);
            }
        }

        $data->set('foo-productunit-quantity-information-overwrite-', $lineItems);
    }
```

The service has the following tag:

```
<tag name="shopware.cart.collector" priority="4999" />
```

When the offcanvas cart is opened, the quantity selection is correct, I can choose from 1-100, but I only can change the quantity that is set for the original values at the product (e.g. purchaseSteps is set to 2).

When setting this inside of the original ProductCartProcessor inside of the enrich function, all is working fine.

What am I missing to make it work in my own collector class?